# How to wrap a method that yields in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, yield

I have a method that prints out a numbered list, yielding to a code block to print a prefix.

```
arr = %w(a b c)

def print_lines(array)
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    prefix = yield index
    puts "#{prefix} #{item}"
  end
end

print_lines(arr) do |index|
  "(#{index})"
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
(0) a
(1) b
(2) c
```

Now I want to wrap `print_lines` in another method and call it.

```
def print_lines_wrapped(array)
  puts 'print_lines_wrapped'
  print_lines(array)
end

print_lines_wrapped(arr) do |index|
  "(#{index})"
end
```

However, this gives me a `LocalJumpError`

```
test_yield.rb:5:in `block in print_lines': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
  from test_yield.rb:4:in `each'
  from test_yield.rb:4:in `each_with_index'
  from test_yield.rb:4:in `print_lines'
  from test_yield.rb:16:in `print_lines_wrapped'
  from test_yield.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

---

Why do I get a `LocalJumpError`?

How can I implement `print_lines_wrapped` such that I can call it like this:

```
print_lines_wrapped(arr) do |index|
  "(#{index})"
end
```

and get the following output:

```
print_lines_wrapped
(0) a
(1) b
(2) c
```

?

Comment: https://repl.it/EKI0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrapper method also has to accept a block and pass it to the wrapped method. There is no implicit passing of the block:

```
def print_lines_wrapped(array, &block)
  puts 'print_lines_wrapped'
  print_lines(array, &block)
end
```

Example:

```
def asdf(&block) puts yield(2) end
def qwer(&block)
  puts "I am going to call asdf"
  asdf &block
end

asdf { |x| x * 3 }
6
=> nil
qwer { |x| x * 5 }
I am going to call asdf
10
=> nil
```

The `&` operator converts its operand into a block if possible

```
 qwer &Proc.new { |x| x * 2 }
 I am going to call asdf
 4
```